# kendo ui grid with stacked columns

Tags: user-interface, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo ui grid to display data.In this now I want to merge three columns.
Something like this.
[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is your requirement clearly.?

Answer (score 0):

In your data you can put html line breaks `<br />`

```
var data = [
    {Id: 1, Location: "Long Side/Short Side<br />Sewer Septic<br />Meter location"},
    {Id: 2, Location: "Long side"},
    {Id: 3, Location: "sewer"},
    {Id: 4, Location: "North-east"},               
];
```

Then when defining the columns for your grid, set the **[encoded](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.encoded)** property to false so that the contents are treated as html:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: data,
    columns: [
        { field: "Id", title: "ID",  },
        { field: "Location", title: "Location", encoded: false },
    ]
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/uHeDe)**